# Invoking a web service from a message flow exposed as a Web service?

Tags: web-services, websphere, security, ibm-mq, messagebroker

I have a message flow exposed as a Web Service. In that flow we are invoking another web service. Flow is mostly generated by dragging a wsdl from a message set to the designer of IBM Websphere Message Broker Tool Kit.
Here is my Flow:

`SoapInput`--> `SubFlow to Expose Service`--> `Subflow to invoke Service`--> `SoapReply`

`SubFlow to Expose Service` is generated by dragging the WSDL and selecting "Expose as a service".

`Subflow to invoke Service` is generated by dragging the WSDL and selecting "Invoke as a service".

Getting invalid param error from service end. I have not received the same error with all services i tried to invoke. This happens only with one service.
Am I doing anything wrong with flow?

Comment: I don't know Message Broker or drag-and-drop flow stuff, but if it's only happening with one service, I'd try to isolate and then microexamine the offending piece. For instance, do your WSDL files all validate fully in the IDE tooling?

Comment: yes ,they validate in the tool (IBM Websphere Message Broker Toolkit)

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues when invoking WebServices (outside Broker) from a message flow, where the cause was a missing Namespace declaration. Try to add  **Tracenodes** in your flow to get better error diagnose.